# Create repeated loop to generate neighbours

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, generator

I'm trying to generate a sublist of nieghbours with below criteria:

- The input would be possible partitions to the list S = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Criteria for Neighbourhood Using Split Operations

- Criteria 1 – Split largest element in the list.
- Criteria 2 – Always split the largest element by //2 
  (e.g. for an element with 3 members will split into 1 with one element and another with 2)
- Criteria 3 – Keep Splitting until no further split possible.

I'm stuck at writing the iterative function for generating the results.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# initialize
neighlists = []
beginning = []
ending = []
newstart = []

inputlist = [[1], [2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

# find the biggest element of the list
def find_biggest(inputlist):
    biggest = max(inputlist, key=len)
    return biggest

biggest = find_biggest(inputlist)
print 'The largest element in the list is: ', biggest

# Function to process biggest component
def process_biggest(biggest):
    split_half = len(biggest)//2
    part_one = [biggest[:split_half]] + [biggest[split_half:]]
    yield part_one

for elem in process_biggest(biggest):
    beginning = elem

# Function to process the rest
def process_therest(inputlist):
    therest = []
    for elem in inputlist:
        if len(elem) < len(biggest) or elem is not biggest:
            therest.append(elem)
    yield therest

for elem in process_therest(inputlist):
    ending = elem

# Function to construct new neighbour
def construct_neighbour(beginning,ending):
    new_neigh = beginning + ending
    yield new_neigh

for neighbour in construct_neighbour(beginning,ending):
    # store the values in the neighlist table
    neighlists.append(sorted(neighbour))

    # use the neighbour as new inputlist
    inputlist = neighbour
```

1. First example:

   - initial input = [[1], [2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
   - first result  = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5, 6]]
   - second result = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
2. Second Example:

   - initial input = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
   - first result  = [[1], [2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
   - second result = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5, 6]]
   - third result  = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
input = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]

def splitList(input):
    length = len(input)
    split = length/2
    left = input[:split]
    right = input[split:]
    return [left, right]

def splitNeighbors(input):
    lengths = map(len, input)
    longest = max(lengths)
    if longest > 1:
        index = lengths.index(longest)
        split = splitList(input[index])
        output = input[:index] + split + input[index+1:]
        return splitNeighbors(output)
    return input

output = splitNeighbors(input)
print(output)
```